# "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404"

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, .htaccess, http

I have been getting a preflight error repeatedly. I have tried numerous methods and nothing works other than putting the call for the API on the same server. Locally it produces the above error.

I have tried altering the .htaccess file to allow "*", and changed other header settings in the .htaccess with no luck.

In Webpack I have tried setting them as well with no luck.

**The network response I get:**

[image]

**The error I get:**

[image]

**The code I use to call the API**

```
var attendeeRequest = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": baseUrl + "attendees",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "api-key": apiKey,
    "dm": dm,
    "event-id": "",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
  }
}

$.ajax(attendeeRequest).done(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

**Root .htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

       # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

       # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
        # BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

       # NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
        # the above regex won't work. You can use the following
        # workaround to get the desired effect:
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

       # Don't compress images
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    </IfModule>

   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

...there is another htaccess file in the folder public_html.

**Public_html .htaccess file**

```
#system System Redirects
    RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?url.com$
    RewriteRule !^dotcom/ /dotcom%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
    #RewriteRule /dotcom%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
    # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   # otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^docs\.url\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.docs\.url\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/docs\.url\.com\/" [R=301,L]

#Disable directory listing
    Options -Indexes

#Set header for security
    Header Set X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"
    Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

#Completes Cache-control and Pragma HTTP headers
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php)$">
        FileETag None
        <ifModule mod_headers.c>
            Header unset ETag
            Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
            Header set Pragma "no-cache"
            Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
        </ifModule>
    </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Looks like your request URL is blank?

Comment: @Timo I removed the url and left blank for security reasons.

Comment: You should post your .htaccess file. The problem is much more likely to be your Apache config than your source code. Also, make sure you configured the correct Apache instance. If you're on a Mac, there is a pre-installed Apache which is likely not the one you're running your app on.

Comment: @NeilGirardi updated as per your request.